# Java ExceptionInInitializer Error in Nifi Processor

Tags: java, exception, static, apache-nifi

I am getting the ExceptionInIntializer error while create an instance of my Nifi processor's class (code below). After looking online, this error results from having an error in the static initializer, which I do not have in my class. Is there anything else in my code that may be causing this error?

```
import ApplicationProperties;
import IndexAttributesUtil;
import ConvertRecordUtil;
import EntityTypeUpdates;
import ViewTypeUtil;
import QueryHelper;
import MServiceLocator;

public class RepProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    protected final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RepProcessor.class);
    private static final ApplicationProperties applicationProperties = new ApplicationProperties();

    protected static final PropertyDescriptor HOST = new PropertyDescriptor.Builder().name("Hostname")
            .description("").required(true)
            .defaultValue(applicationProperties.getHost()).addValidator(StandardValidators.NON_EMPTY_VALIDATOR).build();

    protected static final PropertyDescriptor PORT = new PropertyDescriptor.Builder().name("Port")
            .description("").required(true).defaultValue(applicationProperties.getPort())
            .addValidator(StandardValidators.NON_EMPTY_VALIDATOR).build();

    protected static final PropertyDescriptor TIMEOUT = new PropertyDescriptor.Builder().name("Timeout")
            .description("").required(true)
            .defaultValue(Integer.toString(applicationProperties.getTimeout()))
            .addValidator(StandardValidators.NON_EMPTY_VALIDATOR).build();

    protected static final PropertyDescriptor MAIN_VIEW = new PropertyDescriptor.Builder().name("Main View")
            .description("").required(true).addValidator(StandardValidators.NON_EMPTY_VALIDATOR).build();

    protected static final PropertyDescriptor SUB_VIEW = new PropertyDescriptor.Builder().name("Sub-View")
            .description("").required(false)
            .addValidator(StandardValidators.NON_EMPTY_VALIDATOR).build();

    public static final PropertyDescriptor FETCH_SIZE = new PropertyDescriptor.Builder().name("fetch-size")
            .displayName("Fetch Size")
            .description("")
            .defaultValue("10000").required(true).addValidator(StandardValidators.NON_NEGATIVE_INTEGER_VALIDATOR)
            .build();

    public static final PropertyDescriptor MAX_ROWS_PER_FLOW_FILE = new PropertyDescriptor.Builder()
            .name("max-rows-per-flow-file").displayName("Max Rows Per Flow File")
            .description("")
            .defaultValue("1000").required(true).addValidator(StandardValidators.NON_NEGATIVE_INTEGER_VALIDATOR)
            .build();

    public static final PropertyDescriptor OUTPUT_BATCH_SIZE = new PropertyDescriptor.Builder()
            .name("output-batch-size").displayName("Output Batch Size")
            .description("")
            .defaultValue("0").required(true).addValidator(StandardValidators.NON_NEGATIVE_INTEGER_VALIDATOR).build();

    public static final PropertyDescriptor MAX_FRAGMENTS = new PropertyDescriptor.Builder().name("max-fragments")
            .displayName("Maximum Number of Fragments")
            .description("")
            .defaultValue("0").required(true).addValidator(StandardValidators.NON_NEGATIVE_INTEGER_VALIDATOR).build();

    public static final String A_VIEW = "A_VIEW";
    public static final String B_VIEW = "B_VIEW";
    public static final String C_VIEW = "C_VIEW";
    public static final String D_VIEW = "D_VIEW";
    public static final String E_VIEW = "E_VIEW";
    public static final String F_VIEW = "F_VIEW";
    public static final String G_VIEW = "G_VIEW";
    public static final String H_VIEW = "H_VIEW";
    public static final String I_VIEW = "I_TIE";
    public static final String J_MODE = "J_MODE";

    private long rowCounter = 0;
    private List<PropertyDescriptor> descriptors;
    private Set<Relationship> relationships;

    public static final Relationship REL_SUCCESS = new Relationship.Builder().name("success")
            .description("All status updates will be routed to this relationship").build();
    public static final Relationship REL_FAILURE = new Relationship.Builder().name("failure")
            .description("FlowFiles that failed to process.").build();

    protected MServiceLocator mService;
    private Gson gson = new Gson();

    protected QueryHelper queryHelper;
    protected EntityTypeUpdates EntityTypeUpdates = new EntityTypeUpdates();
    protected ResultSet rs;
    protected ResultSetMetaData rsmd;
    protected ViewTypeUtil viewTypeUtil = new ViewTypeUtil();
    protected IndexAttributesUtil indexAttributesUtil = new IndexAttributesUtil();
    protected ConvertRecordUtil ConvertRecordUtil = new ConvertRecordUtil();

    public RepProcessor() {
        logger.info("comes in the constructor");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", applicationProperties.getKeyStore());
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", applicationProperties.getKeyStorePassword());
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", applicationProperties.getKeyStoreType());
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", applicationProperties.getTrustStore());
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", applicationProperties.getTrustStorePassword());
    }

    @Override
    protected void init(final ProcessorInitializationContext context) {
        final List<PropertyDescriptor> d = new ArrayList<>();

        d.add(HOST);
        d.add(PORT);
        d.add(TIMEOUT);
        d.add(MAIN_VIEW);
        d.add(SUB_VIEW);
        d.add(FETCH_SIZE);
        d.add(MAX_ROWS_PER_FLOW_FILE);
        d.add(MAX_FRAGMENTS);
        d.add(OUTPUT_BATCH_SIZE);

        this.descriptors = Collections.unmodifiableList(d);

        final Set<Relationship> relationships = new HashSet<>();
        relationships.add(REL_SUCCESS);
        relationships.add(REL_FAILURE);
        this.relationships = Collections.unmodifiableSet(relationships);
    }

    @Override
    protected List<PropertyDescriptor> getSupportedPropertyDescriptors() {
        return descriptors;
    }

    @OnScheduled
    public void onScheduled(final ProcessContext context) throws Exception {
        this.mService = makeMServiceLocator(context);
    }

    protected MServiceLocator makeMServiceLocator(ProcessContext context)
            throws NumberFormatException, Exception {
        return new MServiceLocator(context.getProperty(HOST).getValue(), context.getProperty(PORT).getValue(), Integer
                .parseInt(context.getProperty(TIMEOUT).getValue()));
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Relationship> getRelationships() {
        return this.relationships;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTrigger(ProcessContext context, ProcessSession session) throws ProcessException {
        // add code for onTrigger
    }
}
```

I'm creating the instance of this processor in my test class:

```
public class RepProcessorTest {

    EntityTypeUpdates EntityTypeUpdates;
    protected static QueryHelper queryHelper;
    RepProcessor repSpy;
    RepProcessor rep;
    MServiceLocator mService;
    ResultSet rs;
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws NumberFormatException, Exception {
        rep = new RepProcessor();

    }

    @Test
    public void testOnTigger() throws Exception {
    }
```

This is the error where line 44 is rep = new RepProcessor();

```
[ERROR] testOnTigger(processors.RepProcessorTest)  Time elapsed: 0.011 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at processors.RepProcessorTest.setup(RepProcessorTest.java:44)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at processors.RepProcessorTest.setup(RepProcessorTest.java:44)
[ERROR] Errors:
[ERROR]   RepProcessorTest.setup:44 ExceptionInInitializer
```

Comment: Please show the full error from nifi-app.log

Comment: all `static ClassName var =` are the static initializers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ExceptionInitializaerError means there is an error in some static code or object, and since you only have static variables, it is likely from creating one of the PropertyDescriptors.

The error you posted shows that the cause of the error is `NumberFormatException: null`, which means some static code attempted to convert null into a number.

I would guess the issue is this property:

```
protected static final PropertyDescriptor TIMEOUT = new PropertyDescriptor.Builder().name("Timeout")
        .description("").required(true)
        .defaultValue(Integer.toString(applicationProperties.getTimeout()))
        .addValidator(StandardValidators.NON_EMPTY_VALIDATOR).build();
```

If `applicationProperties.getTimeout()` is null, then it will pass null to `Integer.toString()` which would cause the error.